# Dataframe groupby use different function for different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    result       1SD  SLN
Days                         
2     0.021120  0.005954  0.1
2     0.000024  0.000463  0.1
4     0.002268  0.002241  0.1
8     0.002259  0.002053  0.1
```

I want to groupby the index column `'Days'`, but use different formulas for `'result'` (sum), `'1SD'` (average), and `'SLN'` (square root of sum of squares).

```
biodata.groupby('Days').aggregate({'result':np.sum, 'SLN':np.average})
```

gives me what I want partly. How can I also get the square root of sum of squares for the '1SD' column?

Comment: add `'1SD': lambda x: np.sqrt(np.sum(x**2))` to the dict.

Comment: @QuangHoang, Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @QuangHoang This is a relatively unique question, the comment should probably be added as a proper answer, especially considering the enthusiastic way that comments are deleted.